# "She's called me" - does the present perfect tense sound off?

Tags: grammar, usage, present-perfect

Does this use of the present perfect tense sound off to American and British ears? Should it be replaced with the simple past?

> *"Lindsay's not answering. Maybe she left her phone at home." "Well, **she's called** me today, so I don't think that's the case."*

To clarify the context, the speaker wants to say that Lindsay called him an unspecified number of times (could be more than once) today and could still call.

I'm primarily interested in American English, but answers from the UK are also welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a present perfect tense to both ears. There is no difference; a beginner learner might be confused when hearing a **have** shortened to **ve** and a **has** shortened to **s**.

*He's invited me to his party* - *They've done it before* - What makes us not confuse "have/has" to "is" is the fact that the main verb comes in its *participle form* if the tense is is present perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The present perfect doesn't sound off, but American speakers would be more likely to use the simple past in this context. However, the simple past is slightly more likely to imply that she called only once.

The present perfect might be used to give it slightly more emphasis. To specifically call out that she'd called more than once, we would usually say "she's been calling me today."

Comment: Thanks! What if the exchange was _"Maybe she's not in town." "**She's bumped** into me today, so I don't think that's the case."_ Is the present perfect less acceptable now?

Comment: Well, that does sound more odd to my ears. But it's not grammatically or conceptually different in any way. The truly strange thing is that I'd be much, much more likely to use the present perfect in the first person: "Maybe she's not in town." "I've bumped into her today, so I don't think that's the case." I'm going to have to think about it for a while to figure out if I can see any rhyme or reason to these things, though!

Comment: Compare: _"Maybe she won't fire you after all?" "**She's chewed me out** today, so I doubt that."_ or _"**She's smiled** at me today, so you may be right."_ I'm guessing the PP will sound off to you. I think the difference is repeatability.
If you say "I've seen him today" or "She's called me today", you suggest that the seeing or calling could happen again today. "She's bumped into me today" is a pretty one-off event, one unlikely to happen again today, so the PP doesn't fit. As for "I've bumped into her", perhaps you see _your_ bumping into her as more likely to happen than _her_ into you?

Comment: Your examples above are all fine in the present perfect because you're not pointing to a particular time of the day: "She **has chewed** me out *today*." versus "She **chewed** me out *earlier today*." In the second example, you're being more specific about the time, so it takes the simple past whereas, in the first example, it could have happened at any point today, but today is still going on. This differs if you were talking about another day in the past: "She **chewed** me out *yesterday*." (specific time) versus "She **has chewed** me out *this week*." (general time)

Comment: Examples: "I **have done** some bad things *in my life*. I **have committed** horrific crimes (at a general time in the past). I **have spoken** to God *before* and I believe He **has shriven** me of my sin (at some point in the past). In fact, I **did** something really bad *3 days ago* and I **have done** some bad stuff *today* as well as *this whole month*. I *asked* God yesterday to shrive me of my sins of the past month and He **obliged** *that same day*. Being the merciful God that He is, He **shrove** me of my sin (that same day). I **have been blessed** to be in God's grace."

Comment: First, as others have pointed out, I think that the present perfect may actually be more formally correct, but correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are mostly interested in common usage, not technical correctness. That said, I think you may be onto something when you say recurrence has something to do with why we'd choose present perfect or simple past. For example, "she's chewed me out" sounds weirder than "she's smiled at me" because one would hope the smiling would be more likely to recur. But I think it's only one factor of many extremely subtle ones in this area.

Comment: @joiedevivre Indeed, I'm interested in natural usage. Compare also: _"I've seen Star Wars today"_ – why does that sound off, while _"I've seen John today"_ sounds OK? Because you're not going to see Star Wars again today (it's a one-off event), but you might very well see John if he's for example your co-worker. But if John is a childhood friend whom you hadn't seen for 20 years and you just briefly saw him on the subway, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't say "I've seen John today". You would say "I saw John today".

Comment: Someone would ask the question: "Have you seen John today?" It should be in the present perfect to be correct; however, "Did you see John *earlier today*?" is correct.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola Depending on the context, I'd be just as likely to ask "Did you see John today?" I don't know what would happen in England, but in America, no one is going to gasp at that and think I'm uneducated. Tomasz has rather clearly indicated several times that he's interested in a conversation about descriptivist grammar among American speakers, so your extremely prescriptivist "should be in the present perfect" comment seems out of place, at this point.

Comment: "Have you watched Star Wars **today**?" "Yes, I **have watched** Star Wars today. I **watched** it **earlier today**." "Have you ever seen Star Wars (at any time in your life)?" "Yes, I **have seen** Star Wars.  In fact, I **saw** it for the first time today (or earlier today)."

Comment: I wasn't assuming you weren't. You missed the point.

Comment: In this context, I would be very likely to ask, "Did you see John today? He wore the funniest hat." And the reasons that sounds okay support Tomasz's theory about recurrence. I read your answer and previous comments and liked them. All I'm saying is that Tomasz seems to be trying to have a conversation about usage, and you are still talking about what is strictly correct, which seems to be something he already has a pretty good grasp of. Maybe this question about usage would have been better placed on english.stackexchange, though.

Comment: Yeah, probaby. I have no problem with, "Did you see John today?" when I'm sitting in my chair late at night and the day is pretty much over. I like, "Did you see John earlier today? He wore the funniest hat." In this context, the day seems to be over; otherwise, you would have said, "He's wearing the funniest hat."

Comment: I agree that it makes sense at the end of the day. It also makes sense, no matter what time it is, if you think John may no longer be wearing the hat. But all of that supports the recurrence theory, too.

Comment: @joiedevivre Do you agree that _"I've seen Star Wars today"_ sounds bad? Nicholas says (below his answer) that it's OK, but to my ears it sounds **very** unnatural next to "I saw Star Wars today".

Comment: BTW, just because a sentence uses the word "today" (and today is still going on) is not a good enough reason to use the PP. For example, _"I saw my boss making out with his secretary today"_, not _"I've seen my boss making out with his secretary today."_ The second sentence is just incorrect.

Comment: @TomaszP.Szynalski Yes, I agree!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds fine to my American ears although I would probably use the present perfect in the sentence prior as well:

> "Lindsay's not answering. Maybe she **has** left her phone at home." (or **she's left**.)
>
> "Well, she's called me today, so I don't think that's the case."

But I'd like to state that it is common for people to say it in the simple past as an informal way to say it; however, if one were writing a paper, it would probably not be written without being in the present perfect.  The reason for this is that many natives of any language like shortcuts; we don't want to say all of those words if we can convey the information in a simpler form.

Despite the past tense being simpler in common parlance, most people would ask the statements above in a question form this way:

> "Has she called you today?"
>
> "Has she left her phone at home?"

The second example above may be commonly heard in the past simple (whereas the first one would probably not be heard as such), but, in that case, the speaker is usually omitting a clause that he deems implicit to the listener:

> "Did she leave her phone at home (*when she left for work today*)?"

The above construction, however, does not suggest how many times she has called you.  If you want to convey the meaning that she has called you a few times and may call again, I would write it and say it this way:

> "**Has** she **been calling** you all day?"
>
> "She **has been calling** me *all day* today." (or just *all day*)

Comment: Thanks! What if the exchange was _"Maybe she's not in town." "**She's bumped** into me today, so I don't think that's the case."_ Is the present perfect less acceptable now?

Comment: First off, it should be, "What if the exchange **were**..." because you should use the past subjunctive of "to be" there in proper English; second, the present perfect is fine in formal English: "Has she bumped into you today?" "Yes, she **has bumped** into me *today*. In fact, it was *an hour ago* that she **bumped** into me." or "I **saw** her *earlier this morning*, but I **have seen** her around today."

Comment: The PP is fine in my sentence as well? You changed it by adding a question in the PP.

Comment: Yes, your sentence is fine in the present perfect. I've changed it into a question to show you how it would be asked as a question. The present perfect in English is much easier to see in questions than statements: "Have you eaten dinner yet?" "Yes, I have eaten dinner. I ate it earlier." "Have you heard from Amy?" "Yes, I've heard from Amy." "Have you seen my shoes today?" "No, I haven't seen your shoes today." "Have you found your shoes yet?" "Yes, I've found my shoes." "Have you watched Star Wars today?" "Yes, I **have watched** Star Wars today. I actually **watched** it two hours ago."

Answer (score 0):

**"She's called me today."** implies the day is not yet over.

**That is the implication if you use the present perfect here**.

If you say: "She called me today.", the day is not over and it implies, even if **it is not stated**: earlier, at some time of the day, this morning, etc.

This would be true of AmE and BrE.

Comment: it would be hard to say "today" after the day was out

Comment: @Deipatrous You are missing the point. The point is present perfect versus simple past within a specified period of time. You can always use the simple past but you can only use the present perfect with a period of time that is not yet over.

Answer (score 0):

"has called me today" doesn't really address the dramatic scenario you've presented, where you want the statement to say that she has not left her phone at home.

The past tense is idiomatic:

> She had her phone with her when she **called** me earlier today.
>
> She had her phone with her when she **called** me a short while ago.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to remember that the perfect tense emphasises the result as it bears on the present - that present being associated with the tense of *to have*. So in *she'd called me* the "resultative present" is the point of time where that *had* is located. In *she's called me* the auxiliary *has* is in the present of the speaker.

Anyhoo, it sounds fine to my BrEng ears, and I "hear" the implication "so that's how I know" even before "...so I don't think" which reinforces the resultative aspect. It might sound off if the implication of that aspect were absent from the conversation.

*she called me today* is also perfectly fine.